# RESTful framework alternatives to WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, frameworks, .net

Looking for alternatives to the WCF REST start kit, ideally OSS frameworks.

Anyone got a list?

Cheers

Ollie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenRASTA](http://trac.caffeine-it.com/openrasta) is the most mature

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET MVC is a good alternative when it comes to generating REST XML and JSON feeds.

Answer (score 2):

To build a rest architecture in .net you can use GenericHandlers. You can create a GenericHandler that will receive a HTTP message (POST, GET or..) and return a message of the content-type you specify.

For example I create a generic handler on the url:

http://site/getpeople.ashx?gender=female

And call it with the parmeter gender=female, as above the handler will return the following

```
<people>

<person>...</person>
...
<people>
```

And the content type would be text/xml.

This is the simplest way to implement REST web services in .NET

Comment: Using text/xml is not recommended, hasn't been for years. Using application/xhtml+xml is frowned upon in rest architectures. Not worth a downvote, but not worth the original upvote I think.

Comment: Could you, please, specify why is frowned upon?

Comment: Sorry for the slip, should've read application/xml. Its frowned upon because it doesn't expose the actual media type to the UA processor, only some vague notion that it's xml, which doesn't help determine what to do with the content.

Answer (score 2):

I also provide [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net), a modern, code-first, DTO-driven, WCF replacement web services framework encouraging code and remote best-practices for creating DRY, high-perfomance, scalable REST web services.

There's no XML config, or code-gen and your one clean C# web service is enabled on all JSON, XML, SOAP, JSV, CSV, HTML endpoints out-of-the-box, automatically. It includes generic sync/async service clients providing a fast, typed, client/server communication gateway end-to-end.

It also includes [generic sync/async service clients](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#clients) providing a fast, typed, client/server communication gateway end-to-end.

This is the complete example of all the code needed to create a simple web service, that is automatically without any config, registered and made available on all the [web data formats on pre-defined and custom REST-ful routes](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#predefinedroutes):

```
public class Hello {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HelloResponse {
    public string Result { get; set; }
}

public class HelloService : IService<Hello> {
    public object Execute(Hello request) {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}
```

Above service can be called (without any build-steps/code-gen) in C# with the line below:

```
var response = client.Send<HelloResponse>(new Hello { Name = "World!" });
Console.WriteLine(response.Result); // => Hello, World
```

And in jQuery with:

```
$.getJSON('hello/World!', function(r){ 
    alert(r.Result); 
});
```